# visual studio 2012 incompatiblity and editor package not loading correctly?

Tags: visual-studio, incompatibility

I used to use vs 2012 for some month without any problem, today when I want to open my c# project , I got this error message:

```
This program has known compatibility issues

Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop is incompatible with this version of Windows.
```

when I click Run program I got this error:

```
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage' package did not load correctly
```

When I continue with this error message, another error message shows: Visual Studio has stopped working. I need to get it work as soon as posible, any idea?

Comment: thanks for editing, but I need the answer more! ( just kidding )

Comment: Mark my answer if it solved your problem so that others can also benefit from it.

Comment: Here is a solution from [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c1b2d94-5338-47c0-b148-0cf46b4a47d5/microsoftvisualstudioeditorimplementationeditorpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly?forum=visualstudiogeneral&prof=required).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had a similar problem, installing this patch solved it: [KB2781514](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36020)

Answer (score 51):

I just got this error in VS2013 after installing a VS extension.  I fixed it by closing all instances of Visual Studio, then removing **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache**

Comment: Confirmed still working (for a problem randomly cropping up in 2014!). This was not after installing a new extension though, just seemed to occur out of nowhere.

Comment: Same here. I disabled a random extension and restarted, that also fixed it for me. I could enable it afterwards again.

Comment: Got this error after installing some extension, thanks for this easy fix

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me today on VS 2012. The Update mentioned by Jarek didn't install (it complained I already have more stuff installed). Deleting the folder mentioned by squeaky didn't work.

Finally fixed after I installed VS 2012 Update 4 : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305